# "this" belong to it's owner -

Tags: javascript, this

Well, when it comes to `this`, it means the owner of this 
in a function, it's referred to the window 
In HTML event handlers, this refers to the HTML element that received the event:
for Example:

```html
    <button onclick="this.style.display='none'">Click to Remove Me!</button>
    // That's mean instead of this I can write 
    <button onclick="document.querySelector('button').style.display='none'">Click to Remove Me!</button>
    //so with this I specifed this button exactly
```

Take a look at this code I was trying to guess what `this` referred to?:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

//event for BUTTON
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
        //create list element and append it in <ul>
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value  ="";

        //create delete button and append it in <li>
        var delBtn = document.createElement('button')
        delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"))
        delBtn.className = "colorButton"
        li.appendChild(delBtn);

        //apply toggle function(must be out )

        toggle();

        //event listener for the delete button after been created to delete all the node
        delBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.parentNode.remove();//this refer to the Element receive the event=delBtn
        })
    }
})

//-----toggle function---//
function toggle() {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener('click', changeClass)
    }
}

function changeClass() {
    this.classList.toggle('done');
}
```

SO what can I write instead of "this" if possible? or how to replace "this" with its own reference?

1- at delBtn //(event listener) this referred to the delete button, I guess?

2- toggle  ?// (done) is a css class : line-through// this referred to node text inside

here is the [link](https://codepen.io/GeoWasim/pen/yLBZyZY) for this code (it's an example for Shopping List)

Comment: If you try a console.log(this) on your changeClass method you'll see that "this" is the li HTML element where you done your action

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the `li[i]`, the current element, im am not 100% sure, but you could replace `this` with `li[i]`, or you can move the change class function directly into the callback so it may be easier to understand the reference of this

```
  function toggle(){
      for( i=0; i<li.length; i++){
          li[i].addEventListener('click', function changeClass(){
              this.classList.toggle('done');
          })
      }
  }
```